# Generating multi-mode executables with a single CMakeLists.txt

Tags: qt, cmake

Is there a way to create separate executables within one CMakeLists.txt file for the same classes, but for a different intention? This is somewhat like the [DEBUG/RELEASE switch](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_build_multiple_modes_without_switching_.3F), but I need to do a decision at source code level.

Pseudo-CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET_INTENTION(app1 1)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(app1 main.cxx)
SET_INTENTION(app2 2)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(app2 main.cxx)
```

Pseudo-Code main.cxx:

```
if (intention == 1)
  //do something different to intention == 2
```

I tried `ADD_DEFINITIONS` as preprocessor definitions and `#ifdef` in source, but CMake seems to interpret the whole file and got all definitions, no matter at what position the definition was added. Splitting the `ADD_EXECUTABLES()` into two `CMakeLists.txt` (in subfolders) is not really straight forward and leads to problems when using `QT4_WRAP_CPP` and `QT4_WRAP_UI`. I appreciate any ideas / workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`COMPILE_DEFINTIONS` property](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aCOMPILE_DEFINITIONS) looks promising:

```
add_executable(app1 main1.cxx)
get_target_property(APP1_COMPILE_DEFS app1 COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
set_target_property(app1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${APP1_COMPILE_DEFS};INTENTION=1")

add_executable(app2 main2.cxx)
get_target_property(APP2_COMPILE_DEFS app2 COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
set_target_property(app2 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${APP2_COMPILE_DEFS};INTENTION=2")
```

Then use preprocessor `#if INTENTION=1` and so forth in your source files. If you're not using a recent CMake, you may need to mess with the `COMPILE_FLAGS` property instead.